# Underscore replace in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a string

```
var string = "aa--'aa____\_____abccc".
```

I want to replace all underscores with single space. How can I do this using javascript?

I don't want to use any regular expression.  Please suggest the possible ways.

Comment: Why don't you want to use a regular expression? It's the easiest way to do this.

Comment: If you have multiple underscores in a row, should they all be replaced with one space, or should each one become a space?

Comment: Performance is the best answer.

Comment: How many strings are you going to be doing this with that the performance difference is not negligible?

Comment: I also think you underestimate the performance of regular expressions compared to JS code. Regular expressions are usually compiled into DFAs that are very efficient.

Comment: I need one space. I have a scenario. Which says so..

Comment: Is this some sort of code golf? Or your homework for Monday?

Comment: can we use Non DFAs?

Comment: If you don't want to use a regexp, you need to write a loop that copies characters from the source to the destination. For underscores, copy a space to the destination, and use a state variable to remember whether this is the first one or not.

Comment: @Ixg, U got it.. its my homework at my nodeJs class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can replace all duplicate underscores with single underscores, then replace all underscores with spaces:

```
while (string.indexOf('__') != -1) {
  string = string.replace('__', '_');
}
while (string.indexOf('_') != -1) {
  string = string.replace('_', ' ');
}
```

Another way would be to loop through the string and check for underscores and output a space for the first underscore in a group:

```
var result = '';
var space = false;
for (var i = 0; i < string.length; i++) {
  if (string[i] == '_') {
    if (!space) {
      result += ' ';
    }
    space = true;
  } else {
    result += string[i];
    space = false;
  }
}
```

This would of course be simpler and much more efficient using a regular expression:

```
string = string.replace(/_+/g, ' ');
```

Note: If you expect the result to have a backslash, that won't happen. There is no backslash in the string to start with, the character combination `\_` is interpreted as a `_`. If you want to put a backslash in the string you would use `\\` in the string literal.

Answer (score 0):

```
var string = "aa--'aa    \     abccc".
```

done